Computing an abelian group.
Here is the question I am trying to understand:
If I have the following exact sequence  $$0 \to \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z^2 \to A \to 0$$ with the following matrix on the map between the two $\mathbb Z^2$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
How can I compute the abelian group $A$? Or know that it is not unique?

That tells you that you ar emoding out by the subgroup generated by $(1,2)$ and $(2,-1)$ (the columns of the matrix, corresponding to the image of the generators $(1,0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$. You can use the Smith Normal Form to compute the invariant factor decomposition of $A$.

If the map $\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z^2$ is $\phi,$ you require $\phi$ to be one-to-one for $0\to\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z^2$ to be exact. You likewise require $\rho:\mathbb Z^2\to A$ to be onto. Then $A\cong \mathbb Z^2/\ker \rho,$ and $\ker \rho=\operatorname{im} \phi$ means $A\cong \mathbb Z^2/\operatorname{im}\phi,$ and $A$ is always uniquely determined (up to isomorphism) by $\phi.$

But then how can I use the given matrix@ThomasAndrews

@ArturoMagidin I did not get what you said, is there any simpler way of doing it in terms of the usual information known about exact sequences given in the previous comment?

That is "the simple way of doing it in terms of the usual information known about exact sequences."

@ArturoMagidin but the information did not speak about any invariant factors? Do you have a simple definition of an invariant factor? I only know the one of Dummit & Foote and it is not considered as simple to me.

"invariant factor decomposition" is one of the two standard ways of describing a finitely generated abelian group as a direct sum of cyclic groups. It is in any and every book that discusses the structure theorem for finite(ly generated) abelian groups. It is in D&F. The description where the order of each cyclic summand divides the order of the next. The Smith normal form immediately describes what the quotient looks like once you know the kernel. Therefore, it is "the simple way of doing it in terms" of the information you have.

The group $A$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by the image of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ under the given map corresponding to the matrix (and hence is uniquely determined up to isomorphism). Since $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, the image will be generated by the images of these two elements, which are the elements $(1,2)$ and $(2,-1)$. So you want to know the isomorphism type of $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle (1,2),(2,-1)\rangle$.
There are many ad hoc techniques for doing this, depending on the subgroup. But an algorithmic way of doing it is to compute the Smith Normal Form of the matrix that gives you the map. From the Smith Normal form, which will be of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & b
\end{array}\right)$$
with $a\mid b$, you obtain that $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$, which is the invariant factor decomposition of the finitely generated abelian group $A$.
Here we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2\\
2 & -1
\end{array}\right) \stackrel{R_2-2R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left( \begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2\\
0 & -5\\
\end{array}\right) \stackrel{C_2-2C_1}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0\\
0 & -5
\end{array}\right)
\stackrel{-R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0\\
0 & 5
\end{array}\right).
$$
So $A$ is cyclic of order $5$.
